# Unable to start any application

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, crash

Today I tried to rename a few hidden files with the following command in terminal (might be a hint for the solution):

```
for f in .*; do mv "$f" "_$f"; done
```

Now I wanted to start `vlc` and all I got was the messagebox to `ignore`, `report` or `relaunch`.
Most application are not startable, except the few that are loaded (with the dot mark in the dock under the icon).

Non-startable applications:

```
Messages
App Store
Mail
Calendar
iTunes
Terminal
Notes
Chrome
Safari
VLC
Console
Boot Camp Assistant
```

Startable applications:

```
X11
QtCreator
JDownloader
Grapher
Disk Utility
```

In addition, the attempt to run `Mail` from `XTerm` resulted in `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Mail.app with error -10810.`

My system is a MacBook running Yosemite 10.10.5.

My guess is that I for some reason renamed system files and I am afraid that after reboot the system won't start.

Comment: When you ran the command above do you remember which directory you were in inside Terminal? Were you sitting in the root directory?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan: i was under `~/Movies/...`

Comment: @Zaiborg Running your command as an admin just returns `mv: rename . to _.: Invalid argument` and `mv: rename .. to _..: Invalid argument` and renames .localized to  _.localized. Did you prepend `sudo` by accident?

Comment: @klanomath no i did not, i got the error that renaming `.` and `..` is not allowed, the files in that directory were renamed correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a coincidence to me.

Only the files and folder in ~/Movies should be affected.

Even running the command ***with sudo in the root*** of my drive doesn't render my system unbootable:

```
for f in .*; do sudo mv "$f" "_$f"; done
```

Some files and folders are renamed (e.g. _.fseventsd, _.Spotlight-V100, _.Trashes, _.DocumentRevisions-V100, _.vol) but after a restart the important ones will be recreated with the proper name (leaving the renamed folders as they were).

Navigate with Terminal to / and /System/Library/CoreServices and check if anything was renamed; if not reboot otherwise remove all the underscores.

Comment: can you reproduce the error of applications not starting?

Comment: @Zaiborg No absolutely not. Do you have any aliases in your bash profile files?

Comment: `/` and `..../CoreServices` shows no files starting with underscore

Comment: i know some of those words but i've no idea what that should be

Comment: do you know something about `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error  -10810`

Comment: an alias is a "shortcut" for commands. E.g you may create a file .profile in ~/ with the content `alias f="/usr/bin/blah"`. Then you just have to enter f to execute blah.

Comment: no application alias were set

Comment: i am back from reboot, for some reason everything works as expected ... but i wonder what caused that issue